# Project to Tree (looking like JSON) using gremlin

Tags: node.js, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to project a JSON-tree with the data that I have in my Tinkerpop 3.5 database (running on local container, aws neptune is used when deployed).
I have tried using `.tree()` after my repeat, but when I use that (using gremlin for nodejs) - I get a structure with keys that is difficult to work with, it adds `@type` / `@values` as keys and everything is structured in arrays (including the values and key names)

What I want to achieve looks like the code below - but I'd like to "repeat" the `__.out` steps, until there are no more steps to take (the entire tree)... I have tried using `repeat` but, somehow I need to reference the repeated value and put it in the "children" projection.

```js
        const v = await this.g.V(partnerId)
            .out('uses_process').project('title', 'children').by('title')
            .by(
                // This is what I want to "repeat" instead this hard-coded depth
                __.out('uses_process').project('title', 'children').by('title').by(
                    __.out('uses_process').project('title', 'children').by('title').by(
                        __.out('uses_process').project('title').by('title'),
                    ).fold(),
                ).fold(),
            )
            .next();
```

Expected output (and the output I get from the above code, although hard-coded to 3 levels deep):

```json
    {
      "title": "1st Level",
      "children": [
        {
          "title": "2nd level",
          "children": [
            {
              "title": "3rd level",
              "children": {
                "title": "4th level"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here is some sample data

```js
g.addV('Process').property('title', '1st level').as('root').
addV('Process').property('title', '2nd level').as('2nd').addE('uses_process').from('root').to('2nd').
addV('Process').property('title', '3rd level').as('3rd').addE('uses_process').from('2nd').to('3rd').
addV('Process').property('title', '4th level').as('4th').addE('uses_process').from('3rd').to('4th')
```

Would it be possible to get the expected output, without using `.tree()` (and parsing that, which would be tricky with how the current response looks like).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Node.js Gremlin client does not have a built in `Tree` object so what you see there is essentially the GraphSON representation of a tree. This is also true for other clients like the Python one. Only the Java (JVM) based clients have a native `Tree` object that can be de-serialized into.

Using Node.js your best approach is most likely going to be to use some combination of `group` and `project` steps to build a data structure similar in shape to the one that you need.

If you can add some sample data to the question (the `addV` and `addE` steps to build a sample graph) it will help provide a more in depth answer.

**UPDATED 2023-02-28** based on discussion in comments.

When the `group` step is given a label, `x` in this case, it behaves as a side effect (passing through whatever flowed into it). This can be handy for situations like this. We can `group` using the depth of the repeat - `loops` to build a sort of tree like structure. Using your sample data:

```java
g.V().has('title','1st level').
  group('x').by(constant(-1)).by('title').
  repeat(outE().inV().group('x').by(loops()).by('title')).until(not(out())).
  cap('x')
```

Which produces:

```
{-1: ['1st level'], 0: ['2nd level'], 1: ['3rd level'], 2: ['4th level']}
```

I used -1 for the root level as `loops` starts at zero, and we need to `group` before the `repeat` starts or we will either lose the first or last node (depending on where the `group` is placed) if it is located inside the `repeat` body.

Comment: I did check `group` but I didn't manage to solve it though. I've added a snippet with some test-data in `gremlin-console´ format! (thank you!)

Comment: I updated  the answer with an example using `group`. You can expand whatever goes into the `group` just by changing the contents of the second `by`.

Comment: After some work with this I managed to parse it the way I wanted from the structure that this will create! I'm makring this as the accepted answer!